# show NextButton but hide PrevButton in MediaController

Tags: android

is there a way to show just the NextButton, and hide the PrevButton in mediaController?

I can add both the next and prev buttons using the following codes but there does not seem to be any way to add just one button.

(using retroLambda)

```
mediaController.setPrevNextListener(v->handleNextVideoClicked(),null);
```

or

```
mediaController.setPrevNextListeners(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    handleNextVideoClicked();
                }
            }, null);
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is possible, you have to extend media controller class and do the modification yourself, by overriding setAnchorView()

Comment: But be warned if you do this you will have to implement the click listeners etc on these buttons, setAnchorView is the method where mediacontroller creates the view with the buttons

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to just hide the previous button I can think of is this, create a class extend MediaController and override the setAnchorView method but call the super method before doing anything in this method, then just hide the previous button.

```
@Override
public void setAnchorView(View view) {
    super.setAnchorView(view);
    findViewById(com.android.internal.R.id.prev).setVisibility(GONE);
}
```

I haven't got the time to test this, but you can give this a try